# Zend permission error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm getting this error in the log....

What can I do to fix this?

```
2012-06-22T10:53:13+10:00 ERR (3): Zend_Session::start() - /home/commstrat2_web/webrepos/zend/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:469): Error #2 session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_ta9eajdp2oirutoitjuk3vss10, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) Array
/home/commstrat2_web/webrepos/zend/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:479): Error #2 session_write_close() [<a href='function.session-write-close'>function.session-write-close</a>]: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_ta9eajdp2oirutoitjuk3vss10, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) Array
/home/commstrat2_web/webrepos/zend/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:479): Error #2 session_write_close() [<a href='function.session-write-close'>function.session-write-close</a>]: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) Array - Thrown by: /home/commstrat2_web/webrepos/zend/library/Zend/Session.php on line 482
```

Comment: This happened after when I installed GD library using yum install php-gd. What can I do to uninstall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make your resources.session.save_path writable.

You can do :

```
    chmod 775 /path/to/data/session
    In Zend Framework Bootstrap yourProject/application/configs/application.ini:
    resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
```

Comment: Hi, where can I find config.ini? I've only got application.ini in Config

Comment: yourProject/application/configs/application.ini

Comment: No. Had to chmod 777 /var/www/php/session directory

Comment: WOW! but that what i said too right? "make your resources.session.save_path writable."

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selinux, add selinux rule:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/path/to/session'

restorecon -v '/path/to/session'
```